# How to fix 'detailInit out of sync after grid refresh'

Tags: kendo-ui

Background: Let's say I have a kendo grid with 20 entries.  After backend updates/refreshes, when I refresh the grid it comes back with let's say 3 entries. And that's fine depending on my use case.

My problem:
I'm also using detailTemplate with detailInit.  I noticed the detail rows are out of sync.... For example, the new 3 entries are still thinking they belong to the previous 20.

The same issue occurs in reverse.  If I have 3 entries, that refreshes to 20.  If I click on details arrow for the 4th or 5th entry, then an 'undefined' error is thrown.

I successfully refresh the grid via:  gridObject.dataSource.read()

kendo throws an error "can't convert undefined to an object" and the stacktrace points to kendo 'details' related code

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then we'll better understand your issue to give you an answer.